# Triggered send not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, marketing-cloud-connect, triggered-send

i'm trying to make the next triggered send work:

[image: Triggered send definition]

It is active and it is supposed to be working on lead create. Nonetheless the item gets queued in mkt cloud but then becomes an error.

[image: MKT Cloud triggered sends]

Triggered sends on object are working, The one below the example is also on the same object. I´m not really sure whats going on, email passes validation and after create it goes into queue and into trigger data extension.

Anyone have any clue where i went wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you published the trigger in marketing cloud?

Comment: What error code is it giving you?

Comment: Yes,  ![Published in MKT](https://i.imgur.com/vI08pEI.png) I'm not sure if im missing something there.

Comment: How do i check error code? I don't sem to find it.

Comment: If you activated SendLogging to a DE, you can find it there, if not activate it and check again (republishing the triggered send is necessary then). [Marketing Cloud documentation: Create a Email Send Logging Data Extension](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/create_a_send_logging_data_extension/)

Comment: Trying that out. TY, will come back with the error in a couple minutes.

Comment: Might be for another thread, but i dont see the option sendlog template in my template data extensions. Does it need to be enabled?

Comment: Yes, send Logging needs to be enabled by salesforce support.

Comment: Hi Markus, i searched around and it is already enabled. I dont really get how i'm supposed to check my triggered send with it. Under my triggered send i dont have any options for logging data extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resided in the ampscript of the email. It made reference to a field that I didn't fill in my tests. Therefore after trying a couple of times the trigger deactivated itself.